# How can I access a button added in a collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I added buttons in my collection view cells by the code below, where 'myButton' refers to the buttons I try to make access to.

When I click some button outside the collectionView, I want one of my buttons to have its background image changed to have the background of the button clicked, which I tried with 'sendToBox' function below;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell

    cell.myButton.setTitle(self.items[indexPath.item], for: .normal)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    return cell
}

...

@IBAction func keyClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    ...
    sendToBox(object: sender)
    ...
}
...

func sendToBox(object sentObject: UIButton) {

    let imageToSend = sentObject.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
    let imageIdentity = sentObject.restorationIdentifier

    let cell = self.collectionView(ItemCollectionSet, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
    cell.myButton ## blah blah not working!

}
```

So I want to make a direct access to one of the cells I created, and then change the button inside it to have a different appearance. I'm stuck in this matter for a whole day, please help me out.

Comment: In the function `sendToBox` you should use `dequeueReusableCell` as well as you did in `:cellForItemAt:`. However, that's not a good practice what you're trying to do

Comment: Regardless of what you are going to accomplish consider that manipulating the cell is not persistent. When the user scrolls and `cellForItemAt` is called all changes will be reverted. You have to keep all UI states in the data model. Then update the model and reload the item. And you **must not** call  `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:` yourself.

Comment: @Andrew21111 That's a very bad suggestion. **Never** call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForItemAt`. The cell you get will be deallocated immediately when the method exits.

Comment: @vadian as I said in my comment.

Comment: @Andrew21111 Yes, but to make it clear replace *you should use* with *you **must not** use*. It's not a bad practice, it's a no-go.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. However, you explained it in the best way

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. So I should create a data model to handle my collection view and update it, but not handling the collection view cells myself. Hope I understood right.

Comment: Yes, manipulate the view only in `cellForItemAt`. And if you have no choice manipulate the view outside of `cellForItemAt` but you have to update also the model to keep both in sync. `cellForItemAt` can be called at any time.

Comment: @vadian Thanks, I'll try what you said.